# How to make a ScrollView in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview

how can I make a ScrollView which dynamicly adds TextViews to it in the code?
right now I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp"
>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Create TextView"
    />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/Scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>
```

as the layout file and this as my kotlin file:

```
class Abfahrtsmonitor : AppCompatActivity(){
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.abfahrtsmonitor)

    // Variable for counting text view
    var counter: Int = 1;

    // Set a click listener for button widget
    button.setOnClickListener{
        // Create a new TextView instance programmatically
        val text_view: TextView = TextView(this)

        // Creating a LinearLayout.LayoutParams object for text view
        var params : LayoutParams = LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // This will define text         view width
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT // This will define text view     height
        )
 // Display some text on the newly created text view
        text_view.text = "Hi, i am a TextView. Number : $counter"
 // Finally, add the text view to the view group
        Scroll.addView(text_view)

        // Increment the counter
        counter++
```

but now I get the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: you are supposed to add the view to the container inside teh scrollview, better yet why aren't you using a RecyclerView?

Comment: Ah, thats what I was searching for. Thank you, now I only have to find out how RecyclerView works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: `ScrollView` can host only **one direct
>   child**

`ScrollView` can host only one child which means it can hold **only one view** as it's *direct child* so, something like this will help:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    // Content in here ...
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But, this is not the case since you already have `LinearLayout` in the root of the layout so, you may wanna consider placing `ScrollView` as the root and the content inside the `LinearLayout`.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: Thank you, I will try it too

Answer (score 2):

The `ScrollView` itself can only hold one child, in this case your layout. The layout can hold multiple views and you should add you `TextView`s to the layout, not the `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

```
you can use Horizontal scroll view, like below

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/alphabet_horizon_Scroll"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_1"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/a"
                android:onClick="onAbuttonClick"
                android:text="@string/a"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_2"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:text="@string/b"
                android:onClick="onBbuttonClick"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:backgroundTint="@drawable/round_rectangle"
                style="@style/Widget.Button"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_3"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/c"
                android:onClick="onCbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_4"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/d"
                android:onClick="onDbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_5"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/e"
                android:onClick="onEbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_6"
                android:text="@string/f"
                android:onClick="onFbuttonClick"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_7"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/g"
                android:onClick="onGbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_8"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/h"
                android:onClick="onHbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_9"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/i"
                android:onClick="onIbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_10"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/j"
                android:onClick="onJbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_11"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/k"
                android:onClick="onKbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_12"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/l"
                android:onClick="onLbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_13"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/m"
                android:onClick="onMbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_14"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/n"
                android:onClick="onNbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_15"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/o"
                android:onClick="onObuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_16"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/p"
                android:onClick="onPbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_17"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/q"
                android:onClick="onQbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_18"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/r"
                android:onClick="onRbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_19"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/s"
                android:onClick="onSbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_20"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/t"
                android:onClick="onTbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_21"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/u"
                android:onClick="onUbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_22"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/v"
                android:onClick="onVbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_23"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/w"
                android:onClick="onWbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_24"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/x"
                android:onClick="onXbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_25"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/y"
                android:onClick="onYbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_26"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:text="@string/z"
                android:onClick="onZbuttonClick"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="100sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```